# how to make the cards all default to the same size with bootstrap?

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-cards

I'm trying to make these cards the same sizes. In bootstrap, this problem is usually solved with h-100 as shown below, but I still didn't get it.

Now follow all the code below to get a better idea

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";

  var carousels = function () {
    $(".owl-carousel1").owlCarousel({
      loop: true,
      center: true,
      margin: 0,
      responsiveClass: true,
      nav: false,
      responsive: {
        0: {
          items: 1,
          nav: false
        },
        680: {
          items: 2,
          nav: false,
          loop: false
        },
        1000: {
          items: 3,
          nav: true
        }
      }
    });
  };

  (function ($) {
    carousels();
  })(jQuery);
})();
```

```css
body {
  background: aliceblue;
}

.gtco-testimonials {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.gtco-testimonials h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.gtco-testimonials .owl-stage-outer {
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.gtco-testimonials .owl-nav {
  display: none;
}
.gtco-testimonials .owl-dots {
  text-align: center;
}
.gtco-testimonials .owl-dots span {
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #01b0f8;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.gtco-testimonials .owl-dots .active {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.gtco-testimonials .owl-dots .active span {
  background: #01b0f8;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.gtco-testimonials .card {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -7px #c9dff0;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 0;
}
.gtco-testimonials .card .card-img-top {
  max-width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 15px auto 0;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 20px -4px #95abbb;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.gtco-testimonials .card h5 {
  color: #01b0f8;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
.gtco-testimonials .card h5 span {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #666666;
}
.gtco-testimonials .card p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #555;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.gtco-testimonials .active {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.gtco-testimonials .center {
  opacity: 1;
}
.gtco-testimonials .center h5 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.gtco-testimonials .center h5 span {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.gtco-testimonials .center .card-img-top {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .gtco-testimonials {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next, .owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev {
  outline: 0;
}
.owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>CodePen - Testimonials Carousel</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
    <div class="gtco-testimonials">
      <h2>Testimonials Carousel - Cards Comments</h2>
      <div class="owl-carousel owl-carousel1 owl-theme">
        <div>
          <div class="card text-center">
            <img
              class="card-img-top"
              src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/D4D03AQE7KFvlHXMbSw/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0/1691608142028?e=1697673600&v=beta&t=fMtW7RRDyAwY17qu_2XDx-RRyLlfhkPeQIAeLlOdL3I"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5>
                Luana Brenna Negreiros <br />
                <span> Assistente de segurança da informação Jr | Bacharel em Engenharia de Software pela Universidade Federal do Ceará</span>
              </h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                “ Ter o Allan como parceiro de equipes em projetos e acompanhar seu desenvolvimento em startups, ambiente acadêmico e profissional, com certeza foi uma honra, sempre sendo multitarefas
                 com qualidade, criatividade e inovação. Tanto como design de produto como desenvolvedor, gerente de projeto e gestão de pessoas em grupo, desempenhou habilidades de fato admiráveis. ”
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="card text-center">
            <img
              class="card-img-top"
              src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/D4D35AQEGtOAWGRV62A/profile-framedphoto-shrink_800_800/0/1675358199870?e=1693076400&v=beta&t=1emSXI5J5piYembg09VVcOUJfg2VW2j1iKQO3gyrG28"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5>
                Luis Felipe Oliveira<br />
                <span>Gerente de Projetos | Product Owner | Coordenador de Tecnologia e Professor</span>
              </h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                “ Allan Michel tem uma excelente criatividade no tocante a projetos de desenvolvimento de software.
                Com fluidez no backend e no frontend, desenvolve projetos com harmonia e com segmentos muito bem estabelecidos nas análises de requisitos. ”
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div >
          <div class="card text-center">
            <img
              class="card-img-top"
              src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D03AQGTz6u1CkqebA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0/1599489448523?e=1697673600&v=beta&t=iMEVUYWsPjnJbPPn7f9baUVfsBbD3woBDQvvDHZhEcc"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5>
                Anderson Uchôa<br />
                <span> PhD in Software Engineering, Data Scientist R&D </span>
              </h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                “ Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque
                nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat ”
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="card text-center">
            <img
              class="card-img-top"
              src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D03AQGUkSINO8FVCg/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0/1661017159924?e=1697673600&v=beta&t=O3kZPHZbAcqinaPrwJsYKRrPQZ1geSfmi4y3XnK48ZM"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5>
                Elisângela Rodrigues<br />
                <span>Professora Adjunta de Estatística e Ciência de Dados - UFC/Pesquisadora Cidacs/Fiocruz</span>
              </h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                “ Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque
                nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat ”
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- partial -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't see what I can change in the code to make this code how I want it. in addition to the h-100, I've also tried to make some changes with d-flex, but it still didn't work